# Changing a function call dependent on a variable

Tags: c

EDIT:Ill just use case statements, i didn't know if there was a simpler way to do it

ok so i want to call one of 47 different macros that all differ by just a name change
if you input 0 you call "macros" AD0_ADCOMP0 and 31 is AD0_ADCOMP31

this is going to be an assembly program, and I want to set a certain bit of the register number given.

stating AD0_ADCOMP0  = 0x000; works but how do I add in a variable to the macros?

I attempted to do

```
Storelocation = &AD0_ADCOMP0 + offset
Storelocation = 0x000
```

but it doesn't function like the original.

```
AD0_ADCOMP0  = 0x000;
```

Stores 0x000 in the memory location of the register.i feel like this is simple and i cant see it.

stuct is

```
typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    __HWORD hword;
  } ADCOMP;
  struct
  {
    __HWORD hword;
  } ADCOMPB;
} __ADCOMP;



#ifdef __IO_DEFINE
#pragma segment     DATA=IO_AD0,attr=IO,locate=0x1304
#endif


#define AD0_ADCOMP0         (IO_AD0._ADCOMP0.ADCOMP.hword)
```

Comment: What platform? What does the macro look like?

Comment: In C macros aren't called.

Comment: If you have 32 different macros, they may differ in only a small component which you can easily replace with a calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost can generate you multiple `case`:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>
#define DECL(z, n, _data) case n: AD0_ADCOMP ## n = 0x000; break;

...

int input = ...;

switch(input) {
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(47, DECL,)
}
```

turns into:

```
switch(input) {
case 0:
  AD0_ADCOMP0 = 0x000;
  break;

case 1:
  AD0_ADCOMP1 = 0x000;
  break;

...
case 46:
  AD0_ADCOMP46 = 0x000;
  break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int input = ...;

switch(input)
case 0:
  MACRO0;
  break;

case 1:
  MACRO1;
  break;

  ...

case 46:
  MACRO46;
  break;

default:
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
Storelocation = &AD0_ADCOMP0 + offset
Storelocation = 0x000
```

This is a bit nonsensical. As you haven't provided more complete code, I have to assume that `Storelocation` is defined as a `__HWORD *`. When you assign to it, you would need to assign to what it *points to* not to the pointer itself:

```
*Storelocation = 0x000;
```

However, based on the example code you're showing, I have to assume this is for an embedded CPU or microcontroller of some sort, and that `__HWORD` is a 12-bit half-word. You should be aware that it's possible that the assignment via a pointer will not work correctly because the compiler may not process it the same way as a direct assignment to a register-mapped `__HWORD`.